# googleComputeEngineR not connecting in R - Error 400

Tags: r, google-compute-engine

example code : https://cloudyr.github.io/googleComputeEngineR/

```
library(googleComputeEngineR)

Sys.setenv(GCE_AUTH_FILE="auth.json"
        GCE_DEFAULT_PROJECT_ID="dev-example"
        GCE_DEFAULT_ZONE="us-west1-a")
gce_auth()
gce_get_project("dev-example")
```

> Request Status Code: 400
>   Error in checkGoogleAPIError(req) : 
>     JSON fetch error: Invalid value 'dev-example'. Values must match the following regular expression: '(?:(?:[-a-z0-9]{1,63}.)*(?:a-z?):)?(?:[0-9]{1,19}|(?:a-z0-9?))'

The auth.json is a user credential download.

Any suggestion to get it working

Answer (score 1):

opened the json file and found the correct project_id